# Convert geopandas dataframe to GEE feature collection using python

Tags: python, google-earth, geopandas

Given a geopandas dataframe (e.g. df that contains a geometry field), is the following a simplest way to convert it into ee.FeatureCollection?

```
import ee
features=[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    g=ee.Geometry.Point([row['geometry'].x,row['geometry'].y])
    # Define feature with a geometry and 'name' field from the dataframe
    feature = ee.Feature(g,{'name':ee.String(row['name'])})
    features.append(feature)
fc = ee.FeatureCollection(features)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want convert points geodataframe (GeoPandas) to ee.FeatureCollection, you can use this function:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point,Polygon

def make_points(gdf):
    g = [i for i in gdf.geometry]
    features=[]
    for i in range(len(g)):
        g = [i for i in gdf.geometry]
        x,y = g[i].coords.xy
        cords = np.dstack((x,y)).tolist()
        double_list = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, cords)
        single_list = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, double_list)

        g=ee.Geometry.Point(single_list)
        feature = ee.Feature(g)
        features.append(feature)
        #print("done")
        ee_object = ee.FeatureCollection(features)
    return ee_object

points_features_collections = make_points(points_gdf)
```

to do this function I based on this [Reference](https://bikeshbade.com.np/tutorials/Detail/?title=Geo-pandas%20data%20frame%20to%20GEE%20feature%20collection%20using%20Python&code=13)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `FeatureCollection` from a `json` object. So if your geometry data file type is `GeoJson` you can do the following:

```py
# import libraries
import ee
import json

# initialize earth engine client
ee.Initialize()

# load your gemotry data (which should be in GeoJson file)
with open("my_geometry_data.geojson") as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

# construct a FeatureCollection object from the json object
fc = ee.FeatureCollection(geojson)
```

If your geometry data is in different format (`shapefile`, `geopackage`), you can first save it to `GeoJson` then build a `FeatureCollection` object.

Finally, if you don't want to write any conversion code, and want just to convert your `Geopandas.GeoDataFrame` instantly to `ee.FeatureCollection` you can use the python package: [geemap](https://geemap.org/)

`geemap` has several function for converting geometry data to `FeatureCollection`, and vice versa. You can see examples [here](https://geemap.org/notebooks/geopandas/). In your case, you need to use the `geopandas_to_ee` function, so your code would look like this:

```py
# import libraries
import ee
import geemap
import geopandas as gpd

# initialize earth engine client
ee.Initialize()

# load your gemotry data using GeoPandas (which can be stored in different formats)
gdf = gpd.read_file("my_geometry_file.geojson")

# convert to FeatureCollection using one line of code
fc = geemap.geopandas_to_ee(gdf)
```

Note that under the hood, `geemap` is converting the `GeoDataFrame` to a `json` file, and then following the first approach I mentioned above.